# What is the simplest parsing algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, parsers

I want to learn more about parsing techniques, and to do that I'd like to start with the simplest algorithm, understand its limitations, and progress from there.

From what I've seen, the best candidate so far is LL(1). Is this correct?

Comment: To move this from *opinion based*, suggest a definition of *simple*. I think *recursive descent* deceivingly simple.

Comment: @greybeard I mean, there is nothing opinion-based about simplicity, and I think recursive descent is equivalent to LL

Comment: A *finite state automaton* is a simple parser. It can only parse *regular expressions*.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Is it parsing? I mean, does it produce an AST?

Comment: 1) It seems you should just read a book on formal languages. 2)  "Is it parsing? ... Does it produce an AST?" - yes and no depending on what you mean by that. It's "no", because they don't have to (by definition, the only requirement is to check that the string is accepted by the automata). It's "yes", because there is a trivial implementation that builds AST. It also may be "yes" or "no" depending on what memory restrictions you have on the implementation.

Comment: You didn't give a clear definition of parsing.

Comment: @Dmitry If you have a recommandation of such a book I am all for it, thanks

Comment: Not sure what's the best book nowadays, select whatever you like: https://bookauthority.org/books/best-formal-languages-books